# Recursively replacing a dash with an underscore in terminal

Tags: terminal

I am able to replace a space with an underscore recursively.

```
find ./ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

I want to replace `-` with `_`. But this does not work.

```
find ./ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/-/_/g' "{}" \;
```

How can I recursively replace `-` with `_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there much crossover between files that contain spaces and hyphens? Because, if that's not the case, you may not be getting the files you want from the `find` options.

In other words, your second command looks for files containing a space and then replaces all hyphens with underscores in those files. I suspect you should probably be doing this instead:

```
find ./ -depth -name "*-*" -execdir rename 's/-/_/g' "{}" \;
#                      ^
#                note this bit
```